Как импортировать matplotlib установленный через pkg install
Есть termux, в котором установлен matplotlib через pkg install. В pip show matplotlib не отображается, так как через pip install не могу установить.
Есть код, написан на python3.9, в коде используется библиотека matplotlib. Но код не запускается, Module not found. Пытаюсь импортировать через команду
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
И получаю ошибку. Как обратиться к системным файлам termux через код python?
